# Rancher Desktop not noticing file chages, Docker does

Tags: docker, vite, sveltekit, rancher, rancher-desktop

A simple [docker repo](https://github.com/fcrozatier/kit_docker) created to demonstrate HMR of a Sveltekit + Vite app within a docker image / container, works out of the box with native Docker, does not with Rancher Desktop. It seems the external browser connects fine to the container (+ HMR port) but I think it's Rancher not recognising file changes on the fs. Anyone also met this issue?

docker-composer.yml:
https://github.com/fcrozatier/kit_docker/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:
https://github.com/fcrozatier/kit_docker/blob/main/Dockerfile